# I'm wondering what the word is when referencing a table key in a nested table

Tags: lua

I'm wondering what the word is when referencing a table key in a nested table. Let me give a simple example.

```
Food = {
    Fruits = {
        Apple = "red"
    }
}
```

Now, when I put it all together I get:

```
Food.Fruits.Apple
```

When I'm referencing this entire piece of information, not just Apple, but the table entries before it, what would this be called?

A table address? I'm not really sure.

I'd like to know the actual terminology so I don't refer to everything as "that thing".

Comment: "An expression"? I'm not aware of special phase given to "chaining table/dictionary/object access" in any language.. "chaining" itself, perhaps, but it usually has other connotations.

Comment: A chained table lookup?